# Projecting new samples into existing PCA space?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pca

I have a dataset and I have performed PCA analysis using `scikit-learn`. I have another dataset with the same features and would like to project the data into the same PCA space as created by the first dataset.

My understanding is that I have to transform and center the data in the same way the original dataset was and then use the eigenvectors to rotate the data.

I'm a little stuck as to do this based on the output from the `sklearn.decomposition.PCA library`.

**So far I have**

```
X1 = np.loadtxt(fname="dataset1.txt")
pca = PCA(n_components=50)
pca.fit_transform(X1)
pca_result = pca.transform(X1)

X2 = np.loadtxt(fname="dataset2.txt")
```

Does anyone have any pointers on how this can be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some redundancy there. If you perform fit_transform(), it returns the principal components while also saving the parameters to the object. If you have a new sample, you then use only transform. See below:

```
X1 = np.loadtxt(fname="dataset1.txt")
pca = PCA(n_components=50)
Y1 = pca.fit_transform(X1)

X2 = np.loadtxt(fname="dataset2.txt")
Y2 = pca.transform(X2)
```

Comment: Thanks - just what I was after!

Answer (score 0):

**Fit it using the first dataset and then transform the second using the fitted model.**

```
X1 = np.loadtxt(fname="dataset1.txt")
pca = PCA(n_components=50) # define model
pca.fit(X1) # fit model
pca_result = pca.transform(X1) # project the dataset 1

X2 = np.loadtxt(fname="dataset2.txt")
pca_results_2 = pca.transform(X2) # project the dataset 2 using the fitted model
```